# Check if shell script is run via pipe

Tags: shell, unix, pipe

my script should be run through a pipe like this:

`echo "hello" | mysript.sh`

I read the input with `input=cat`

However if it's run without a pipe cat waits for input - how can I fix this?

Comment: In general, btw, I agree w/ trojanfoe -- this is typically a feature, not a bug; it lets you type input at the console, and follow it up with a `^D` when done.

Comment: BTW, this question probably shouldn't be limited to pipes, as you're doing here. You'd want `myscript <hello.txt` not to abort, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to fix as it sounds like it works like every other utility that accepts input via `stdin`. That's a good thing.

Comment: Not *every* other utility. `tar`, for instance, will exit with an error if run without an input file and with stdin pointed to a TTY in creation mode.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Depends what options you give:  `tar cf - . | (cd /path; tar xfv -)` should work fine.

Comment: Sure -- there's no tar content writing to or reading from a TTY in that example.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The question mentions nothing about TTYs, and nor does my answer.

Comment: The question mentions "hanging waiting for input" happening without an input source provided. Sure, they specify "pipe" in the text, but that's sloppiness in form rather than any interpretation of reasonable intent; `myscript <in.txt` is surely intended to proceed without error, whether `in.txt` is a regular file, a named FIFO, &c.